# Java - Accurate Font Height without Graphics

Tags: java, fonts

I have an object called GUIText that has a string text, font, font style, color and decoration (underline, overline, strikethrough). I can use this method to get the width of the GUIText, according to its text and font:

```
public int getWidth() {
    return Display.getCanvas().getFontMetrics(this.font.toJavaFont()).stringWidth(
            this.text);
}
```

(Display.getCanvas() returns a JComponent).
I know about getFontMetrics().getHeight(), but this returns a number too big. Actually, the font.getSize() is closer to the actual height than the getFontMetrics().getHeight(), but is not exact. I need to know this so I can draw a line over a GUIText for overline decorating.

Comment: FontMetrics#getHeight will return the total height of the font (from the heightest to lowest point of the font), if it doesn't, this generally means that the font is not providing the correct metric information

Comment: You should also take a look at [Working with text APIs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/text/index.html) for more information about how fonts are measured and renderers

Answer (score 2):

Maybe the `TextLayout` class is what you are looking for. It will give you the exact size:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.font.*;
import java.awt.geom.*;

public class DrawTest extends JPanel
{
    String text;

    public DrawTest(String text)
    {
        this.text = text;
        setFont( new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 24) );
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g;
        g2d.setFont( getFont() );
        g2d.setPaint(Color.RED);

        //  Draw text using FontMetrics

        FontMetrics fm = g2d.getFontMetrics();
        Rectangle2D rect = fm.getStringBounds(text, g2d);
        rect.setRect(rect.getX() + 100, rect.getY() + 50, rect.getWidth(), rect.getHeight());
        g2d.draw(rect);

        //  Draw text using TextLayout

        g2d.setPaint(Color.BLACK);

        Point2D loc = new Point2D.Float(100, 50);
        FontRenderContext frc = g2d.getFontRenderContext();
        TextLayout layout = new TextLayout(text, getFont(), frc);
        layout.draw(g2d, (float)loc.getX(), (float)loc.getY());

        Rectangle2D bounds = layout.getBounds();
        bounds.setRect(bounds.getX()+loc.getX(), bounds.getY()+loc.getY(), bounds.getWidth(), bounds.getHeight());
        g2d.draw(bounds);
    }

    private static void createAndShowUI()
    {
        DrawTest text = new DrawTest("This is some ugly test");

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("SSCCE");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add( text );
        frame.setSize(400, 200);
        frame.setLocationByPlatform( true );
        frame.setVisible( true );
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                createAndShowUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: I do not have access to a Graphics object

Comment: @MCMastery, how do you expect to "draw a line..." if you don't have a Graphics object?

Comment: When I draw a line I have it.

Comment: I use a class I made my self as a middle-man in drawing things

Comment: `When I draw a line I have it.` - then that is when you should do your calculations. Get rid of the "middle-man".